# How to call results from LEFT JOIN mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have this query:

```
$query = '
SELECT * FROM "rdm_item" 
    LEFT JOIN "rdm_tag" ON "rdm_item"."aff_id" = "rdm_tag"."aff_type_id"     
    WHERE "rdm_item"."aff_publish" = 4 
    ORDER BY "rdm_item"."aff_id" 
    DESC LIMIT 0,12';
```

**and tables:**

rdm_item columns: `aff_id/aff_publish/...`

rdm_tag columns: `aff_id/type_id/...`

I could get results.

But for `$result[0]['aff_id']` I expect `rdm_item.aff_id` but it return `rdm_tag.aff_id`

what's my problem?

Comment: Steve is right. Try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the columns you want from the select, prefixing them with the table name.  For example:

```
$query = '
SELECT rdm_item.aff_id FROM "rdm_item" 
    LEFT JOIN "rdm_tag" ON "rdm_item"."aff_id" = "rdm_tag"."aff_type_id"     
    WHERE "rdm_item"."aff_publish" = 4 
    ORDER BY "rdm_item"."aff_id" 
    DESC LIMIT 0,12';
```

If you have duplicate column names in two tables (i.e.  aff_id) use an identifier, e.g.

```
$query = '
SELECT rdm_item.aff_id as rdm_item_aff_id, rdm_tag.aff_id as rdm_tag_aff_id FROM "rdm_item" 
    LEFT JOIN "rdm_tag" ON "rdm_item"."aff_id" = "rdm_tag"."aff_type_id"     
    WHERE "rdm_item"."aff_publish" = 4 
    ORDER BY "rdm_item"."aff_id" 
    DESC LIMIT 0,12';
```

You can then refer to the correct column with something like `result[0]['rdm_item_aff_id']`.